# How to insert images and text into Word document

Tags: .net, vb.net, image, ms-word, office-interop

I'm writing application in VB.NET Visual Studio 2010. My goal is to insert many images into the Word document from selected location on hard drive but every image should be separated from each other by a line of text `"picture no 1,2..."` etc. I have written the program which can choose some pictures and insert them into doc file but images aren't separated by text lines. I don't know how to do this so I’m asking for your help .

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) _
        Handles Button1.Click
    Dim oword As New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application()
    Dim odoc As Word.Document
    oword = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    oword.Visible = True
    odoc = oword.Documents.Add
    Dim ofd As New OpenFileDialog()
    ofd.Filter = "Images (*.BMP;*.JPG;*.GIF)|*.BMP;*.JPG;*.GIF"
    ofd.Title = "Choose your images...."
    ofd.Multiselect = True
    If ofd.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
        For Each filename As String In ofd.FileNames
            Dim oPara2, oPara3 As Word.Paragraph
            oPara2 = odoc.Content.Paragraphs.Add
            Dim map As InlineShape = odoc.InlineShapes.AddPicture _
                (filename, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,Type.Missing) 
            map.Height = 350
            map.Width = 350
            oPara3 = odoc.Content.Paragraphs.Add
            oPara3.Range.Font.Name = "Arial"
            oPara3.Range.Font.Size = 14
            oPara3.Range.Text = "Picture no "
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

PRoblem 1: You're instantiating Word incorrectly. Use this at the top of the code sample you show us and get rid of the CreateObject:

```
Dim oword As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application = New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application()
```

Problem 2: Best to work with Range objects when you need to position things in a Word document. Think of a Range like a Selection, except it's not visible on-screen and you can have as many Range objects as you need (while only one Selection is possible).

There are many way to achieve your goal; something along these lines is my personal preference:

```
Dim oPara2 As Word.Paragraph, oRng as Word.Range
oPara2 = odoc.Content.Paragraphs.Add()
oRng = oPara2.Range
oRng.Collapse(Word.WdCollapseDirection.wdCollapseStart)
Dim map As InlineShape = odoc.InlineShapes.AddPicture _
            (filename, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, oRng) 
map.Height = 350
map.Width = 350
oRng = map.Range
oRng.InsertAfter(vbCr)
oRng.Collapse(Word.WdCollapseDirection.wdCollapseEnd)
oRng.Text = "Picture no " & vbCr
oRng.Font.Name = "Arial"
oRng.Font.Size = 14
oRng.Collapse(Word.WdCollapseDirection.wdCollapseEnd)
NEXT
```

Comment: Glad to hear it :-) When you have a moment, if you could activate the "Answer checkmark" just to the left of the Answer, under the "helpful" counter? That help SO site administration and other users with similar problems recognize that the question has had a useable answer.